# Create React App with Express API cookie authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, create-react-app

My setup is thus:

Node server running Express which runs an API.
Inside a subdirectory `client` is a Create React App project, with the `proxy` field set to the URL of the Express API.

I start both processes and access the CRA in my browser, which sends requests to the Express API through the proxy.

This all works fine.

In production, I will build the CRA and serve it from the Express app, like so:

```
app.use('/api/:controller', (req, res, next) => {
    return router(req, res, next)
})
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(`${__dirname}/client/build/index.html`));
})
```

My only roadblock is how to handle authentication. I could quite easily do an onload `fetch` request back to the API when the React app is initialised in the browser to see if the user has a session, but it seems like a waste.

In development (and I guess production for that matter), what would be a good way to 1) read the cookie from the incoming request and 2) pass on the `currentUser` object to the `index.html` above (in production) or to CRA in development.

To clarify, I was wondering if there are any specific CRA recipes for handling authentication from the server, *before* it sends the response back to the browser? (in this dual-purpose codebase setup)

Exact issue: In development, because I'm running `yarn run cra`, it's spinning up it's own webpack dev server, which serves the React app. So I don't *believe* I can really get at the request before it gets sent back to the browser.

Comment: Damn this was two years ago, not a single answer. I've been busting my ass the past few weeks trying to figure this out. Did you eventually figure it out Ben?

I think we have a similar setup. Except we'll have 2 separate repos. Repo 1: Node / Express and Repo 2: CRA

When you hit the CRA route for /login, express actually redirects to our SSO, login and redirects back to the express app which loads the react app again with the jwt stored in localStorage.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this working with CRA.